# Python hangman, removing blanks from the answer pool and refining what can be input

Tags: python, loops, append

I'm currently learning Python and trying to build a set of minigames to solidify my basic knowledge, however there are a few things I want to do with my game that others on here haven't (from what I've seen, at least), and that is remove whitespace between words from the answer and the "masked" answer. I assume it would be done as an "if, else" sort of statement? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
for x in range(i): ## where i is the word
  if x == " ":
    continue ## wouldn't it be pointless to append something that you don't want to change?
  else:
    word.append('_')
```

Another question I had was regarding a loop statement I have at the beginning of my game, within this loop I have an if/else stating that if there are more than 1 letter in the guess, it'll return a statement telling the user that's not valid. But the game immediately stops working afterword.

```
while guesses < 6:
  guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
   if len(guess) > 1:
    return "One letter at a time!"
   else: continue
```

I'm not quite sure what to add to my code to make it continue asking for input after this.

Here's my full code, it's currently not working for me after asking for input... I took the code it from another user on here and fixed it to my tastes, since their game didn't use more than one word and didn't check to see if there was more than one letter being input when prompted, and I figured it would be good practice to modify existing code to make it do a bit more than it originally does.

```
def hangman():
  guesses = 0
  word = []
  guessed = []
  words = ["bichon frise", "maltese", "dachshund",  "pomeranian", "golden retriever", "shih tzu", "rottweiler", "pit bull", "beagle", "poodle", "akita", "basset hound", "border collie", "boston terrier", "boxer", "bulldog", "chow chow", "chihuahua", "chinese crested", "french bulldog", "great dane", "great pyrenees", "greyhound", "icelandic sheepdog", "irish wolfhound", "komondor", "mastiff", "shnauzer", "pekingese", "welsh corgi", "redhound coonhound", "samoyed", "shiba inu", "weimaraner", "whippet", "italian greyhound", "yorkshire terrier"]


  print "Welcome to Hangman. The words chosen are the names of various breeds of dogs, try and guess the word before the man is hung!"

  answer = random.choice(words)
  i = len(answer)
  print "The length of the word is", i, "characters long"
  for x in range(i): 
    if x == " ":
      continue
  else:
      word.append('_')

  while guesses < 6:
    guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
    if len(guess) > 1:
      return "One letter at a time!"
    else:
      continue


    if (guess in i):
      print "The letter is in the word."
      for index, letter in enumerate(i):
        if letter == guess:
          word[index] = guess 
      guessed.append(guess)
    else:
      print "The letter is not in the word"
      guesses = guesses + 1
      guessed.append(guess)

    print "You have guessed these letters so far: %s)" % (''.join(guessed))
    print "Letters matched so far %s): %" (''.join(word))

    if ''.join(word) == answer:
      break

  if guesses == 6:
    print "You didn't guess the right answer in time! The answer was %s" % answer
  else:
    print "You guessed the word!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> remove whitespace between words from the answer.

Given `i` (`i` as a string?) is the string, you probably should not use `range(..)` on it since `range` expects an `int`. Furthermore why do you build a list instead of a new string? You can however easily use a generator:

```
word = ''.join(c for c in i if c != ' ')
```

`word` is here a string that contains all characters of `i` that are not `' '`. If you want however to generate a sequence of underscores, you can use:

```
word = ''.join('_' for c in i if c != ' ')
```

If you want to construct a list (which the remainder of the code expects), you can use *list comprehension*:

```
word = ['_' for c in i if c != ' ']
```

> it'll return a statement telling the user that's not valid. But the game immediately stops working afterword (*sic.*).

That's because you use a `return` statement: `return` means you jump out of the function and (optionally) return a value. You probably want to `print(..)`:

```
guesses = 0
while guesses < 6:
    guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
    if len(guess) > 1:
        print("One letter at a time!")
    else:
        #process char
        continue
```

I also noticed you use `continue`. `continue` means that you abandon the remainder of the iteration and take the next one, so it means you will not process the query. So you have to remove the `continue` part:

```
while guesses < 6:
    guess = raw_input("Please guess a letter: ")
    if len(guess) > 1:
        print("One letter at a time!")
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl: well in the first code fragment the first line states: ` ## where i is the word` furthermore it does not make any sense to compare `x` with `' '` anyway.

Comment: Ah, forgot about what return does, whoops! And the word list you suggested is a lot shorter and better than the range statement I had set up! Thank you. I'm sure I'll figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

`return` ends the function right there, use `print` instead:

```
print "One letter at a time!"
```

As for the whitespace, why don't you append the space to the masked word? That way, the player won't have to guess it, can see that there are spaces,  and your `join`-check will work:

```
for x in range(i): 
  if x == " ":
    word.append(' ')
  else:
    word.append('_')
```

Comment: More needs to be changed to correct the loop part. And then there's the thing about whitespace too.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I used your code, however shortly after I found a better alternative that made writing the code a whole lot easier, without using the range function.

Which was at the "Letters matches so far" line, instead of simply just join and calling back to the list, I put: ''.join(l for l in rightguesses else "_" for l in answer) the only downside to this is I don't know how to add a an additional elif to make whitespaces in answer remain as such....

Comment: @kat Use  `else "_ "[l==' ']` instead of `else "_"`  ;)

Comment: !!! Thank you so much, my games now fully functional! But can you explain that to me? Are the brackets saying "if l is " " just put whitespace?"

Comment: `"_ "[l==" "]` works as follows: `l==" "` is a `bool`. If a `bool` is used as an index, it is coerced to an `int`: `True -> 1`, `False -> 0`. So it will pick either the first (False, 0) or second (True, 1) letter from the string `"_ "`, so a space if `l` is a space and an underscore otherwise.